# Filter a model in Django Restframework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am setting up a Django REST application where peopple can review restaurants. So far I have those serializers:

```
class RestaurantIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantId
        field = fields = '__all__'


class RestaurantReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantReview
        field = fields = '__all__'


class StarterPicsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StarterPics
        fields = '__all__'

   def validate_restaurant_review_id(self, value):                
       if value.review_author != self.context['request'].user:            
           raise serializers.ValidationError("User has not reviewed the restaurant")               
       if RestaurantReview.objects.filter(id=value.id, 
                                           restaurant_id=value.restaurant_id).exists():    
          return value       
       raise serializers.ValidationError('Not the right restaurant')
```

My models:

```
 class RestaurantId(models.Model):
        maps_id = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True)
        adress = models.CharField(max_length=240)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=140)

class RestaurantReview(models.Model):    
    review_author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantId, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    

class StarterPics(models.Model):
    restaurant_review_id = models.OneToOneField(RestaurantReview,
                                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pics_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantId, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)    
    picture_1 = models.ImageField()
```

my views:

```
class RestaurantIdViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.RestaurantId.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RestaurantIdSerializer


class RestaurantReviewViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.RestaurantReview.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RestaurantReviewSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(review_author=self.request.user)


class StarterPicsViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.StarterPics.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StarterPicsSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnReviewOrReadOnly]
```

So what I need is that if the author is not the author of the review he can't POST any pictures in StarterPics. This part of my validation is working fine.

But I also need to be sure that even if the User is the author of the review he can't change the restaurant_id and POST the picture with another restaurant_id. The second part of `validate_restaurant_review_id` doesn't work because the User can POST on a review if he is the author but can change the restaurant_id.

So my RestaurantReview.objects.filter is wrongly setup. How should it be written?

Answer (score 0):

when you say `validate_restaurant_review_id` doesn't work, does it mean you are getting error, if yes then you cannot access other object parameter by using value.restaurant_id because you are calling validate_your_field_name and this function is supposed to give only value for that attribute.

And also user would not be able to change other restaurant id, as in PUT method of model viewset (which is update, and assuming you are using it), it will handle automatically, as you need to pass pk for updating comment

Comment: No I mean it doesn't work because only the author of the review can POST a picture but he can change the  restaurant_id to another restaurant_id and it will work. So my validation is not working properly.

Comment: views added to the question